# Linq bool Take two value

Tags: c#, linq

I used this way to check if exist or not

```
bool isExist = dtData.AsEnumerable()
                               .Any(Rowx => strValue1 == Rowx.Field<String>("Value1"));
```

My question how if I want to check more than one value, to check that this both value is exist in the row or not, for example

```
bool isExist = dtData.AsEnumerable()
                               .Any(Rowx => strValue1 == Rowx.Field<String>("Value1")
                                And Rowx => strValue2 == Rowx.Field<String>("Value2"));
```

Answer (score 1):

Use following

```
bool isExist = dtData.AsEnumerable()
                               .Any(Rowx => (strValue1 == Rowx.Field<String>("Value1")
                                           && strValue2 == Rowx.Field<String>("Value2")));
```